# CSS/HTML suggestions in VSCode like in WebStorm

Tags: visual-studio-code, settings, webstorm

I have a question about the VSCode CSS/HTML suggestions. I would like it to work like in WebStorm.

**First problem**: when I type whole property name there are no suggestions.

[image]

But when I type `di` and select correct property and press tab/enter I have suggestions but in WebStorm it's always. Even if I press backspace and space again. In VSCode after backspace I cant see any suggestions any more.

[image]

**Second problem**: in HTML I don't see any suggestions (.css saved)

[image]

Extensions which I use:
**IntelliSense for CSS, SCSS class names in HTML, Slim and SCSS**, **HTML CSS Support** and **SCSS IntelliSense**
These are my user settings.

```
{
"explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
"explorer.confirmDelete": false,
"workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
"material-icon-theme.folders.theme": "specific",
"material-icon-theme.hidesExplorerArrows": false,
"material-icon-theme.folders.color": "#90a4ae",
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
"editor.wordWrap": "on",
"eslint.enable": false,
"git.autofetch": true,
"git.enableSmartCommit": true,
"files.autoSave": "off",
"workbench.editor.enablePreview": false,
"html-css-class-completion.enableEmmetSupport": true,
"trailing-spaces.trimOnSave": true,
"workbench.colorTheme": "Atom One Dark",
"php.validate.run": "onType",
"php.suggest.basic": true,
"editor.formatOnPaste": true,
"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "blade": "html",
    "javascript": "javascriptreact"
},
"editor.tabCompletion": "on",
"editor.find.autoFindInSelection": true,
"editor.snippetSuggestions": "top"
}
```

I wonder if it's the fault of my configuration or the lack of any extensions or maybe I have too many of them (21).